# How to make sure ajax is fully loading content using .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

We have a site where on the left we are displaying our products and on the right shows the product the user clicks on (on same page).  When the page loads we have the first product being shown on the right by default, when the user clicks on a new product then the right columns changes to show the new product (via ajax).

Here is how I have the ajax setup:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var defaultValue = $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a:first").attr("href");

    $(".main").load(defaultValue);

  $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
      //alert(addressValue );
    $(".main").load(addressValue);

    //$("a.woocommerce-main-image").addClass("image-popup-no-margins");

  });

});
</script>
```

We are using magnific popup to show the larger image of the product when the user clicks on the (right sides) main product image.

This works great for the first (default) product but when the user clicks on a new product and the content to the right changes, then the user clicks on the main image, the pop up fails to load.  So in other words it works when you first load the page and the default product is shown, but fails to fire when a new product is clicked.

Here is the product-image.php filter which just adds our class of image-popup-no-margins:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image image-popup-no-margins" title="%s">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );
```

And in the footer we have this:

```
$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      closeBtnInside: false,
      fixedContentPos: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
      image: {
        verticalFit: true
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
      }
    });
```

Im may have given too much info here but I felt better safe then sorry, so perhaps its better if I give you a link for you to see what I mean.  When you visit the page, click on the big image on the right and you should see the popup functioning.  Now try clicking on one of the products on the left so the main image on right changes and try to click it again, the default behavior happens instead of our pop up.

I checked classes and everything looks fine, I'm sure it has to do with the ajax but can't get it worked out.

**Update:**
After more tinkering with this I think the problem is that the .load is not 'reloading' the content when the anchor is clicked.  Like I said it works when you first load the page and click on the first image, but when you change the image and the ajax is called I don't think it really reloads the content in the main container.  How would I make sure the ajax is fully loading the content like it does when you first open the page?  If you go to the site and click the big image on right, it works, change the image by clicking on a product from the left and the pop up fails to work and so does the "Tag It" pop up…  Maybe this is less specific to magnific popup and more of a basic ajax

Comment: Actually whats interesting if I unfocus and then focus the window (ie switch tabs away and back) it works for the new right-hand content

Comment: you have an error in the console when you clic images on the left

Comment: Hmm seems the focus thing is not related.. actually its just taking time for the content to load.. once they are completed it works.. try watching with firebug

Comment: Specifically the get request for the popup is taking 5.8 seconds!! on my connection.. once this completes it works perfectly

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @tieson using 1.10.2 I think, Im going to add the link back for you guys to take a look but will remove it once solved for privacy reasons

Comment: Im not sure if I am using the right term but I think I need some sort of "flushing" functionality in my ajax so when a new image from left is clicked then it fully loads the new content on the right as if it were loading the whole page (without refreshing) -- hope I am making sense

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server is just quite slow and delivering the content required for the new popup. you can see the get requests by viewing the firebug console. once these have completed it works perfectly. I suggest upgrading for hosting or finding another way to deliver the higher quality images faster, such as imgur or other image hosting services.

Comment: Thanks for that, we are in the process of migrating all images to S3 server

Comment: I checked the console in firebug and waited for the request to complete - it still fails to work after the request completes...

Comment: Hm.. your website absolutely works on my computer, firefox 27.0.1

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was indeed with the magnific popup, replaced it with Fancybox and all seems to be functional correctly -- Thanks for the help guys